# PHP Sort multidimensional array by two criterias

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array and I need to sort it, first by "key_1" and (in case of more of one similar values in "key_1") sort it by "key_2"
... how can I do this, any idea?

Thanks!

```
$my_array[0]['key_1'] = 2;
$my_array[0]['key_2'] = 300;

$my_array[1]['key_1'] = 2;
$my_array[1]['key_2'] = 100;

$my_array[2]['key_1'] = 1;
$my_array[2]['key_2'] = 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution :

```
function my_sort($a, $b) {
  if ($a['key_1']==$b['key_1']) {
    if ($a['key_2']==$b['key_2']) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return ($a['key_2']>$b['key_2']) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  } else {
    return ($a['key_1']>$b['key_1']) ? 1 : -1;
  }
}

usort($my_array, 'my_sort');
```